# Google Sheets: Compare Two Values in Different Cells and Insert Symbol In Another Cell Depending on Comparison Result

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, insert, symbols

In Google Sheets, I want to write a formula that compares the values between two cells in the same row and then inserts a specific symbol in another cell depending on which one is larger.  Please see screen shot below:

[image]

In my above example, since the value in cell B3 is larger than the value in cell D3, I want to insert the upward pointing delta symbol in cell C3.

Since the value in B4 is smaller than the value in D4, I want to insert the downward pointing delta symbol in cell C4.

Since the value of B5 is equal to the value in D5, I do not insert a symbol at all.

Is there a way for me to enter a formula (or use AppsScript if formula is not available) in column C that would allow me to automatically populate the correct delta symbol?  The delta symbol can be found here in Google Sheets: [here](https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/data-analytics/delta-symbol-excel/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifs(B3>D3,char(9650),B3<D3,char(9660),1,)
```

- *Use conditional formatting to color code the symbol*

[image]

Comment: Amazing!  My triangles have to be black though ... is there a way to make them black instead of red or green?

Comment: by default they are black!!